# Grub v0.97 doesn't display new boot options after editing menu.lst file

Tags: debian, dual-boot, grub, grub-legacy

I recently installed Android x86 7.1-r3-i386 in a partition in the same hard drive my Debian 10 i386 system is.

I edited `/boot/grub/menu.lst` to add a new option to run Android x86 in the boot menu. But after running `update-grub` and rebooting my computer the new entry doesn't show.

Here is the content of `/boot/grub/menu.lst`

> ```
> # menu.lst - See: grub(8), info grub, update-grub(8)
> #            grub-install(8), grub-floppy(8),
> #            grub-md5-crypt, /usr/share/doc/grub
> #            and /usr/share/doc/grub-legacy-doc/.
>
> ## default num
> # Set the default entry to the entry number NUM. Numbering starts from 0, and
> # the entry number 0 is the default if the command is not used.
> #
> # You can specify 'saved' instead of a number. In this case, the default entry
> # is the entry saved with the command 'savedefault'.
> # WARNING: If you are using dmraid do not change this entry to 'saved' or your
> # array will desync and will not let you boot your system.
> default       0
>
> ## timeout sec
> # Set a timeout, in SEC seconds, before automatically booting the default entry
> # (normally the first entry defined).
> timeout       5
>
> # Pretty colours
> color cyan/blue white/blue
>
> ## password ['--md5'] passwd
> # If used in the first section of a menu file, disable all interactive editing
> # control (menu entry editor and command-line)  and entries protected by the
> # command 'lock'
> # e.g. password topsecret
> #      password --md5 $1$gLhU0/$aW78kHK1QfV3P2b2znUoe/
> # password topsecret
>
> #
> # examples
> #
> # title       Windows 95/98/NT/2000
> # root        (hd0,0)
> # makeactive
> # chainloader +1
> #
> # title       Linux
> # root        (hd0,1)
> # kernel  /vmlinuz root=/dev/hda2 ro
> #
>
> #
> # Put static boot stanzas before and/or after AUTOMAGIC KERNEL LIST
>
> ### BEGIN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
> ## lines between the AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST markers will be modified
> ## by the debian update-grub script except for the default options below
>
> ## DO NOT UNCOMMENT THEM, Just edit them to your needs
>
> ## ## Start Default Options ##
> ## default kernel options
> ## default kernel options for automagic boot options
> ## If you want special options for specific kernels use kopt_x_y_z
> ## where x.y.z is kernel version. Minor versions can be omitted.
> ## e.g. kopt=root=/dev/hda1 ro
> ##      kopt_2_6_8=root=/dev/hdc1 ro
> ##      kopt_2_6_8_2_686=root=/dev/hdc2 ro
> # kopt=root=UUID=936b24d8-6e0b-4f5c-847f-0c1414bc48b1 ro
>
> ## default grub root device
> ## e.g. groot=(hd0,0)
> # groot=(hd0,0)
>
> ## should update-grub create alternative automagic boot options
> ## e.g. alternative=true
> ##      alternative=false
> # alternative=true
>
> ## should update-grub lock alternative automagic boot options
> ## e.g. lockalternative=true
> ##      lockalternative=false
> # lockalternative=false
>
> ## additional options to use with the default boot option, but not with the
> ## alternatives
> ## e.g. defoptions=vga=791 resume=/dev/hda5
> # defoptions=
>
> ## should update-grub lock old automagic boot options
> ## e.g. lockold=false
> ##      lockold=true
> # lockold=false
>
> ## Xen hypervisor options to use with the default Xen boot option
> # xenhopt=
>
> ## Xen Linux kernel options to use with the default Xen boot option
> # xenkopt=console=tty0
>
> ## altoption boot targets option
> ## multiple altoptions lines are allowed
> ## e.g. altoptions=(extra menu suffix) extra boot options
> ##      altoptions=(single-user) single
> # altoptions=(single-user mode) single
>
> ## controls how many kernels should be put into the menu.lst
> ## only counts the first occurence of a kernel, not the
> ## alternative kernel options
> ## e.g. howmany=all
> ##      howmany=7
> # howmany=all
>
> ## should update-grub create memtest86 boot option
> ## e.g. memtest86=true
> ##      memtest86=false
> # memtest86=true
>
> ## should update-grub adjust the value of the default booted system
> ## can be true or false
> # updatedefaultentry=false
>
> ## should update-grub add savedefault to the default options
> ## can be true or false
> # savedefault=false
>
> ## ## End Default Options ##
>
> title     Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 4.19.0-8-686-pae
> root      (hd0,0)
> kernel        /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-8-686-pae root=UUID=936b24d8-6e0b-4f5c-847f-0c1414bc48b1 ro 
> initrd        /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-8-686-pae
>
> title     Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 4.19.0-8-686-pae (single-user mode)
> root      (hd0,0)
> kernel        /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-8-686-pae root=UUID=936b24d8-6e0b-4f5c-847f-0c1414bc48b1 ro single
> initrd        /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-8-686-pae
>
> ### END DEBIAN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
>
> title           Android x86
> root            (hd0,3)
> kernel          /android-7.1-r3/kernel root=UUID=033e8fc7-4cfe-9454-bc59-df7329ca862d
> initrd          /android-7.1-r3/initrd.img
> ```

What am I missing?

Comment: is there another menu.lst file in some other directory?

Comment: There's a menu.lst~ but it has the same content

Comment: Final newline? Some tools ignore the last line if no newline ends it